# Controlling placement of package warnings in the log

Tags: tex-core, warnings, documentclass-writing

Is there any way to control where in the log file or console output `\PackageWarning` or `\ClassWarning` messages get placed? I have a class warning (generated by my own document class) that gets buried at the beginning of the log file which I'd like to place at the end, close to where the warnings about labels appear.  Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps not the right platform or workflow but [LateX Makefile](http://code.google.com/p/latex-makefile/) does handle errors and warnings (including at least *some* package warnings), displaying them more prominently than the default log output.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but since this is a class file that will be used by many different users, I want to control the placement myself as much as possible.

Comment: Very interesting question, Alan! When reading the `biblatex` doc., I saw the description of the `logreq` package, which "provides a frontend for writing machine-readable messages to an auxiliary log file." The output seems to be a set of instructions described in the XML format (reminds me of the Java `ant` buildfiles). Since I'm not sure if we can selectively redirect the compiler output, a similar approach to this package might help (`.log` - `.xml`, messages - commands, and so forth). Another "dirty" idea is to use `grep`/`awk`/`sed` to "filter" the `.log` file and get the package messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `\ClassWarningNoLine` that suppresses the line number indication:

```
\AtEndDocument{\ClassWarningNoLine{myclass}{I've done something}}
```

Comment: Great. That's very helpful. I hadn't noticed those versions of the warning commands, and for this kind of warning, it's exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 3):

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\let\OldClassWarning\ClassWarning
\renewcommand*{\ClassWarning}[2]{\AtEndDocument{\OldClassWarning{#1}{#2}}}

\ClassWarning{book}{Class warning.}

\begin{document}
This is a test document.
\typeout{Test.}
\end{document}​
```

and was able to shove a `\ClassWarning` to the end of the document. That is, the log file showed

```
Test.
...
Class book Warning: Class warning.
```

rather than the other way around. Does this qualify as "exact placement"?

Comment: Thanks.  I discovered this too, after I posted the question, but I thought I'd let someone else answer.  In fact, in my case it's not really necessary to redefine `\ClassWarning`, but simply to wrap it in `\AtEndDocument`.  I think this is about as exact as we'll get.  I'll wait to see if anyone else has a different solution.

Comment: Sure, if you have access to `\ClassWarning` in the document class, redefinition is not required.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't so clear :-)  I was assuming from inside the class itself; you were assuming from inside a user document.  I've clarified the question for posterity.

Comment: Ahhh, now it makes more sense. I wonder whether the [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence) would be of any help. It *captures* (gobbles) warning messages and may provide a means for producing a warning together with another.

Comment: That's an interesting package, but it would be somewhat perverse to use it inside a class, I think. :-)  Using `\AtEndDocument` seems to put things far enough to the end for my purposes.